# Set Default Language on Pygments.rb | Redcarpet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, syntax-highlighting, pygments, redcarpet

I'm trying to set a fix language for [Pygments.rb](https://github.com/tmm1/pygments.rb), Javascript. I'm using [Redcarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet) for the Markdown.
So far i'm here:

# Model.rb
    before_save :render_source

```
def render_source
  require 'redcarpet'
  renderer = PygmentizeHTMLSOURCE
  extensions = {fenced_code_blocks: true}
  redcarpet = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(renderer, extensions)
  self.rendered_source = redcarpet.render self.source
end

class PygmentizeHTMLSOURCE < Redcarpet::Render::HTML
  def block_code(code, language)
    Pygments.highlight(code, :lexer => 'javascript', options: {linenos: 'table'})
  end
end
```

Right now i'm passing the `:lexer => 'javascript'` but can't get rid of the language option for the block. If i remove the 'language' i get `wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)`

Does this have something to do with Redcarpet ? How can i set the lexer to default to javascript ?

My Main Problem is that i want the initial `:text` to be the CLEAR input of the user. I don't want to store the

````
```javascript

```
````

in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it !!

I was using a Block-Level Call that was predefined from Redcarpet. That block contained (code, language).

What i had to use was a Pre/post Process Callback for the **Whole Document**

```
  class PygmentizeHTMLSOURCE < Redcarpet::Render::HTML
    def preprocess(full_document)
      Pygments.highlight(full_document, :lexer => 'javascript', options: {linenos: 'table'})
    end
  end
```

For further customization heres a list of the [Pygment Formatters](http://pygments-doc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/formatters/html.html).